# How to select rows whose values belong to a list in R

Tags: filter, subset

I have the table below from which I would like to extract rows. The rule is that the *Date* must be inside a list of dates:

I have the following table, which I name *df*:

| Date | value |
| --- | --- |
| "2022-03-31" | 1 |
| "2022-06-30" | 2 |
| "2022-09-30" | 3 |
| "2022-12-31" | 4 |

I created a list: *myQuarters* <- c("2022-06-30", "2022-09-30"). I would like to select only the rows defined by *myQuarters*. The format of column *Date* is, of course: "%Y/%m/%d")

I would like to get the following result

| Date | value |
| --- | --- |
| "2022-06-30" | 2 |
| "2022-09-30" | 3 |

I tried this but it didn't work. No row was selectes

my_df <- subset(df, df$Date %in% myQuarters)

Any hint to solve my problem? Maybe I'm not manipulating dates correctly